# Streaming some data from PHP to C++

Tags: php, c++, boost, stream, boost-beast

My goal is to send, from a C++ app, a simple GET query to PHP, such as "do re mi fa sol" and get some data I can play.

The PHP script will return a stream of bytes that I will interpret in the C++ client.
I read one byte to know the nature of the next segment (text or WAV audio file).
I read 2 bytes for the size of the next segment.
I read the segment data and deal with it accordingly.

I am no expert in neither C++ nor PHP but I managed, using the boost library.
It works fine as long as the data I send is small.
I the data reaches a certain size it's messed up: I get an unvalid byte for the nature of the segment (the first one I read).

I think the limit after which it's messed up is 8192Bytes, and I'm guessing it's just writing back at the beginning of the buffer?

I tried a few things:
- changing the size of the buffer in which I read the socket.
- make my PHP script sleep, but the c++ client seams to wait for the request to be over, so I just have a delay before I get the same error.
- try to flush in my PHP script, and ob-flush... it doesn't work any better, and it seams these methods add some bytes to the output somehow.

Here is my code:
C++

```
    std::string host = "192.168.1.232";
    std::string port = "80";
    std::string path = "/praat/play.php";
    int httpVersion = 11;

    boost::asio::io_context ioc;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver{ ioc };
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{ ioc };

    auto const results = resolver.resolve( host, port );

    boost::asio::connect( socket, results.begin(), results.end() );

    boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> req{ boost::beast::http::verb::get, path, httpVersion };
    req.set( boost::beast::http::field::host, host );
    req.set( boost::beast::http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING );

    boost::beast::http::write( socket, req );


    OutputDebugString( L"████ Let's read the request:\n" );

    std::array< byte, 32 > buf;
    bool parsingHeader = true;
    std::string header = "";
    std::deque< byte > data;
    unsigned long cumul = 0;

    while ( true ) {

        boost::system::error_code error;

        int len = socket.read_some( boost::asio::buffer( buf ), error );

        cumul += len;

        OutputDebugString((L"████ Error value: " + std::to_wstring(error.value()) + L"\n").c_str());

        OutputDebugString( ( L"████ Bytes received: " + std::to_wstring( len ) + L" for a total of " + std::to_wstring( cumul ) + L"\n" ).c_str() );

        if ( error == boost::asio::error::eof ) {

            OutputDebugString(L"████ End of file\n");
            break;
        }

        std::string s = (char *)buf.data();
        s = s.substr( 0, len );

        if ( parsingHeader ) {

            std::size_t index = s.find( "\r\n\r\n" );

            if ( index != std::string::npos ) {

                header += s.substr( 0, index );

                std::wstring ws( header.begin(), header.end() );

                OutputDebugString( L"████ We got a header:\n" );
                OutputDebugString( ( ws + L"\n" ).c_str() );

                int dataLen = len - index - 4;

                data.resize( dataLen );

                std::copy( std::begin( buf ) + index + 4, std::begin( buf ) + len, std::begin( data ) );

                parsingHeader = false;
            }
            else {

                header += s;
            }
        }
        else {

            int currentSize;

            currentSize = data.size();

            data.resize( currentSize + len );

            std::copy( std::begin(buf), std::begin(buf) + len, std::begin(data) + currentSize );
        }

        if ( !parsingHeader ) {

            OutputDebugString( ( L"████ Data size: " + std::to_wstring( data.size() ) + L"\n" ).c_str() );

            while ( data.size() != 0 ) {

                int typeFlag = ( unsigned int )data[0];

                OutputDebugString( ( L"████ First byte: " + std::to_wstring( typeFlag ) + L"\n" ).c_str() );

                switch ( typeFlag ) {

                    case 1:
                        OutputDebugString(L"████ We have text");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        OutputDebugString(L"████ We have sound");
                        break;
                    default:
                        OutputDebugString( L"████ Unhandled byte\n" );
                        goto exitloop;
                }

                if ( data.size() < 3 ) {

                    OutputDebugString( L" but not enough bytes to read its length.\n" );
                    break;
                }

                int segmentSize = int( (unsigned char)data[1] << 8 | (unsigned char)data[2] );

                OutputDebugString( ( L" for " + std::to_wstring( segmentSize )  + L" bytes" ).c_str() );

                if ( data.size() < 3 + segmentSize ) {

                    OutputDebugString( L" but they are not ready yet.\n" );
                    break;
                }

                OutputDebugString( L".\n" );

                if ( typeFlag == 1 ) {

                    std::wstring encoded( data.begin() + 3, data.begin() + 3 + segmentSize );

                    std::wstring text = base64_decode( encoded );

                    OutputDebugString( ( text + L"\n" ).c_str() );
                }
                else if (typeFlag == 2) {


                }

                data.erase( data.begin(), data.begin() + 3 + segmentSize );
            }
        }
    }

exitloop:



    boost::system::error_code ec;
    socket.shutdown( boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec );

    if ( ec && ec != boost::system::errc::not_connected )
        throw boost::system::system_error{ ec };
```

PHP:

```
<?php


set_time_limit( 0 );

// header or not, it doesn't seam to change anything.
/*header( 'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' );
header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate' );
header( 'Pragma: public' );*/

//$partition = $_GET[ "partition" ];
$partition = "do"; //,re,mi,fa,sol! la:si?";
$separators = " ,.;:!?";

chdir( ".." );

function echoObject( $object ) {

    $json = json_encode( $object );

    $encoded = base64_encode( $json );

    echo pack( "Cn", 1, strlen( $encoded ) );
    echo $encoded;
}

function play( $partition, $start, $length ) {

    $note = substr( $partition, $start, $length );

    $object = new stdClass();
    $object->type = "highlight";
    $object->start = $start;
    $object->length = $length;
    $object->note = $note;

    echoObject( $object );

    $wav = "notes/" . $note . ".wav";

    $fileHandle = fopen( $wav, 'rb' );

    fseek( $fileHandle, 32 );

    $infos = unpack( 'Vsize', fread( $fileHandle, 4 ) );

    $size = intval( $infos[ 'size' ] );

    fread( $fileHandle, 4 ); //remove the 4 bytes for "data";

    $total = 0;

    do {

    $len = min( $size - $total, 256 );

    echo pack( "Cn", 2, $len );
    echo fread( $fileHandle, $len );

    $total += $len;

    //usleep( 100000 );

    echoObject( array( "total" => $total, "size" => $size ) );
    }
    while( $total < $size );

    fclose( $fileHandle );
}

$start = 0;
$length = 0;

echoObject( array( "type"=> "start" ) );

do {

    if ( strpos( $separators, substr( $partition, $start + $length, 1 ) ) ) {

    if ( $length == 0 ) {

        $start++;
    }
    else {

        play( $partition, $start, $length );

        $start += $length + 1;
        $length = 0;
    }
    }
    else {

    $length++;

    if ( $start + $length == strlen( $partition ) ) {

        play( $partition, $start, $length );
    }
    }
}
while( $start + $length < strlen( $partition ) );

echoObject( array( "type"=> "over" ) );

?>
```

At this point I am stuck.
Any help would be welcome.
Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**

After changing to another method, following elarmando sample, I have the following code on the client:

```
boost::asio::streambuf response;
    boost::asio::read_until( socket, response, "\r\n" );

    // Check that response is OK.
    std::istream response_stream( &response );
    std::string http_version;
    response_stream >> http_version;
    unsigned int status_code;
    response_stream >> status_code;
    std::string status_message;
    std::getline( response_stream, status_message );

    if ( !response_stream || http_version.substr( 0, 5 ) != "HTTP/" ) {

        OutputDebugString( L"████ Invalid response\n" );
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    if ( status_code != 200 ) {

        OutputDebugString( ( L"████ Response returned with status code " + std::to_wstring( status_code ) + L"\n" ).c_str() );
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    // Read the response headers, which are terminated by a blank line.
    boost::asio::read_until( socket, response, "\r\n\r\n" );

    OutputDebugString( L"████ We have a header:\n" );

    // Process the response headers.
    std::string header;
    while ( std::getline( response_stream, header ) && header != "\r" )
        OutputDebugString( ( std::wstring( header.begin(), header.end() ) + L"\n" ).c_str() );
    OutputDebugString( L"\n" );

    OutputDebugString( L"████ Now let us parse the body:\n" );

    std::deque< byte > data;
    auto handle = [ &data, &response ]() -> bool {

        const BYTE* test = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const BYTE*>(response.data());

        int currentSize;

        currentSize = data.size();

        data.resize( currentSize + response.size() );

        std::copy( test, test + response.size(), std::begin(data) + currentSize );

        response.consume(response.size());

        OutputDebugString((L"████ Data end - begin: " + std::to_wstring( data.end() - data.begin() ) + L"\n").c_str());
        OutputDebugString((L"████ Data size: " + std::to_wstring(data.size()) + L"\n").c_str());

        while ( data.size() != 0 ) {

            int typeFlag = (unsigned int)data[0];

            OutputDebugString( ( L"████ First byte: " + std::to_wstring(typeFlag) + L"\n" ).c_str());

            switch (typeFlag) {

                case 1:
                    OutputDebugString( L"████ We have text" );
                    break;
                case 2:
                    OutputDebugString( L"████ We have sound" );
                    break;
                default:
                    OutputDebugString( L"████ Unhandled byte\n" );
                    return false;
            }

            if ( data.size() < 3 ) {

                OutputDebugString( L" but not enough bytes to read its length.\n" );
                break;
            }

            int segmentSize = int( ( unsigned char)data[1] << 8 | (unsigned char)data[2] );

            OutputDebugString( ( L" for " + std::to_wstring( segmentSize ) + L" bytes" ).c_str());

            if ( data.size() < 3 + segmentSize) {

                OutputDebugString( L" but they are not ready yet.\n" );
                break;
            }

            OutputDebugString( L".\n" );

            if (typeFlag == 1) {

                std::wstring encoded( data.begin() + 3, data.begin() + 3 + segmentSize );

                OutputDebugString( ( encoded + L"\n").c_str() );

                std::wstring text = base64_decode( encoded );

                OutputDebugString( ( text + L"\n" ).c_str() );
            }
            else if (typeFlag == 2) {

                //play the audio here
            }

            OutputDebugString((L"████ Data size before erase: " + std::to_wstring(data.size()) + L"\n").c_str());

            data.erase( data.begin(), data.begin() + 3 + segmentSize );

            OutputDebugString((L"████ Data size after resize: " + std::to_wstring(data.size()) + L"\n").c_str());
        }

        //OutputDebugString( ( L"████ Size: " + std::to_wstring( data.size() ) + L"\n").c_str() );

        return true;
    };

    if ( response.size() > 0 )
        if ( !handle() ) goto parsingerror;

    boost::system::error_code error;

    while (boost::asio::read(socket, response, boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1), error))
        if ( !handle() ) goto parsingerror;

    if ( error != boost::asio::error::eof )
        throw boost::system::system_error( error );

    goto done;

parsingerror:

    int typeFlag = (unsigned int)data[0];
    OutputDebugString( ( L"████ First byte is: " + std::to_wstring( typeFlag ) + L"\n" ).c_str() );

done:

    OutputDebugString( L"████ Done\n" );

    return S_FALSE;
```

And I have the exact same result.

But then I realized something, and that is that when the content is bigger than a certain value ( in my case it seams to be something around 8000, I'm guessing 8192) the header of the response changes from:

```
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 14:09:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 7977
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

to:

```
Date: Thu, 31 May 2018 14:09:31 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So I guess the chunked encoding requires extra parsing.

Comment: I see a lot of problems with your C++ code, after the call to `http::write`. My question is this. If you are sending an HTTP request, then why not just use Beast to read the HTTP response from the PHP script, instead of trying to do it yourself (which contains numerous bugs)?

Comment: @VinnieFalco That's what I was trying to do at first. But I could only find few examples and they wouldn't build. If you have anything for me I'd gladly give it a try.

Comment: Follow the boost example to read the http headers. This will not fix the problem but the code would be easier to read and debug. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/sync_client.cpp

Comment: That's weird, because all the examples compile for me, on several environments. I wouldn't use Boost 1.49 as @elarmando suggests, because Beast is only available in Boost 1.66 and later.

Comment: @elarmando Thank you but the result is exactly the same. But I noticed something regarding the header I get. I updated my post.

Comment: @Vinnie Falco I can't even find the sample I tried that didn't build. Google seams to hate the "::" as I cannot find much when I try "html::read_some". The compilation error was ocuring when I was setting up the allocator.Anyway I think I found the issue, as I explain in the updated post.
Do you think beast, if I ever manage to make it work, handle this "chuncked" mode? Or will I still have to implement it myself?

Comment: In case of transfer-encoding is chunked you will need to process the content response differently. This is the process to read the content: 1) First read the headers normally, 2) Then read the first line until  "\r\n". The read line is the content size of the first chunk. 3) Use obtained size to read the chunk until another "\r\n". 4) Read again until "\r\n", this will give the size of the second chunk. 5)Read second chunk... Repeat this until the size of the chunk is 0. Here is an example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding

Comment: Beast is perfectly capable of handling chunked encoding both for sending and receiving. It is transparent (no action is required on your part).